# superimpose two parabolas on each other and limit display ranges

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Suppose I want to trace two parabolas in the same graph:

```
y=2*x**2+0.05
y=1.66*x**2-1.25
```

and plot independent combinations of x and y as points with it. In addition, I want to limit the x and y ranges for each of the parabolas. For example: parabola 1 should be shown from x=-0.75 to x=0.75 and y=0 to y=0.8 and parabola 2 should be shown from x=-3 to +3 and y=-2.5 to y=10.

What would be the easiest way to do this?

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me what you want to achieve. Is your goal to generate a plot that fills the space between the two parabolas?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is what you are looking for (I am not clear about how you would set different ranges for two plots) but how about simply

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = np.arange(-0.75, 0.75, 0.01)
y1 = 2*x1**2+0.05

x2 = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.01)
y2 = 1.66*x2**2-1.25

plt.plot(x1, y1)
plt.plot(x2, y2)

plt.ylim(-2.5, 10)
```

(maybe playing with ranges in the code)?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best soluution, but the easiest way I can think of is using Pillow to render them yourself.